# Buttons not clickable in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have a custom ListView + ArrayAdapter with expandable list items. When I expand a list item and scroll so that it is no longer visible, the buttons in the expanded layout are no longer clickable when I scroll back. The issue isn't consistent though; sometimes, when I scroll down and back up, the buttons are clickable. When I expand the list item and don't scroll, the buttons work just fine, so that is why I think it must be an error in ArrayAdapter.

I have onClick set in XML, and when I have checked for clickable in getView of my ArrayAdapter, the buttons are clickable.

Here is the getView of the ArrayAdapter; I am using multiple layouts in the adapter, and only the ParameterListItem is expandable/the item in question.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ExpandableListItem object = mData.get(position);
    final View view = storedViews.get(position);

    if (object instanceof FillerParamListItem) {
        return view;
    }

    //Load the holder
    ExpandingViewHolder holder = (ExpandingViewHolder) view.getTag();

    //Handle collapsing and expanding the cells
    if (((ParameterActivity) activity).listView.isExpanded() && !object.isExpanded()) {
        view.setAlpha(.20f);
    } else {
        view.setAlpha(1f);
    }

    if (object instanceof SwitchParamListItem) {
        ...
    } else if (object instanceof DomainListItem) {
        ...
    } else if (object instanceof ParameterListItem) {
        if (((ParameterActivity) activity).listView.isExpanded() && !object.isExpanded()) {
            holder.expandingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.valueTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (activity.getCoreApplication().getOfflineMode()) {
                holder.collapsedLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_list_item_background_offline));
            } else {
                holder.collapsedLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_list_item_background));
            }

            holder.collapsedLayout.setElevation(0);
        } else {
            if (object.isExpanded()) {
                holder.expandingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.valueTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.valueEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (activity.getCoreApplication().getOfflineMode()) {
                    holder.expandingLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.parameter_activity_expanded_layout_background_offline));
                    holder.collapsedLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.parameter_activity_expanded_layout_background_offline));
                } else {
                    holder.expandingLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.parameter_activity_expanded_layout_background));
                    holder.collapsedLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.parameter_activity_expanded_layout_background));
                }

                holder.collapsedLayout.setElevation(3.0f * activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            } else {
                holder.expandingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.valueTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.valueEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (activity.getCoreApplication().getOfflineMode()) {
                    holder.collapsedLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_list_item_background_offline));
                } else {
                    holder.collapsedLayout.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_list_item_background));
                }

                holder.collapsedLayout.setElevation(0);
            }
        }

        if (object.getImgResource() != ExpandableListItem.NO_ICON) {
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(object.getImage());
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        holder.titleTextView.setText(object.name);
        holder.valueTextView.setText(object.getValue());
        holder.unitTextView.setText(object.unitSym);

        holder.descriptionTextView.setText(object.description);
        holder.useTextView.setText(object.hint);

        ParameterListItem parameterListItem = (ParameterListItem) object;

        //Register listeners for the seeker bar and EditText for this specific parameter
        TextListener editTextListener = new TextListener(parameterListItem, activity, view, holder.valueEditText);
        holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(parameterListItem.getListener());
        holder.valueEditText.addTextChangedListener(editTextListener);
        parameterListItem.registerTextListener(editTextListener);
        holder.valueEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(editTextListener);
        parameterListItem.registerSeekBar(holder.seekbar);

        holder.valueEditText.setTag("PROGRAM");
        holder.valueEditText.setText(object.getValue());
        holder.valueEditText.setTag("NONE");

        //show value and symbols within the expanded cells for the seeker bar track
        holder.minValueTextView.setText(Util.getStringForFloat(parameterListItem.getMinValue()) + object.unitSym);
        holder.maxValueTextView.setText(Util.getStringForFloat(parameterListItem.getMaxValue()) + object.unitSym);
        holder.middleValueTextView.setText(Util.getStringForFloat((parameterListItem.getMaxValue() + parameterListItem.getMinValue()) / 2) + object.unitSym);

        view.setOnTouchListener(editTextListener);
    }

    object.assocView = view;

    return view;
}
```

Here's my XML for the Expandable List Item (the first RelativeLayout is the collapsed view, while the second is the expanded view):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parentlinearlayoutid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:clipToPadding="false"

android:paddingBottom="3dp"

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_background"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="530dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

    android:background="@drawable/main_list_item_background"

    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_edit_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_units"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"

        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_value"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_units"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_units"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:text="deg"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.idunnololz.expandingcells.ExpandingLayout
    android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_expanding_layout"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_width="530dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:background="@drawable/parameter_activity_expanded_layout_background"

    android:elevation="3dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"

    android:visibility="visible">

    <View
        android:layout_width="475dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"

        android:background="@color/secondary_button_color"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_slider_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_min_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

            android:text="-20"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize= "18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_middle_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:text="-5"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize= "18sp"/>

        <com.usb.exo.ui.CustomSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_slider"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:progress="1"
            android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"

            android:thumb="@drawable/slidebutton"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:isScrollContainer="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_max_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize= "18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_description_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@id/parameter_activity_parameter_slider_layout"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_description_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="7dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"

            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_description_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"

            android:text="Increasing angle will bend user forward. Adjusts user comfort in sitting."
            android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_use_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@id/parameter_activity_parameter_description_layout"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_use_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="7dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"

            android:text="Use"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_use_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:paddingTop="10dp"

            android:text="Bends user forward or backward while sitting. Angle of torso relative to vertical."
            android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@id/parameter_activity_parameter_use_layout"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_cancel_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:onClick="cancelClicked"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_undo_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="undoClicked"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

            android:text="Undo Last Change"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/parameter_activity_parameter_apply_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="applyClicked"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

            android:text="Apply"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.idunnololz.expandingcells.ExpandingLayout>
```

I expect "cancelClicked" to be called, but it is not. There does seem to be some action with the button (the background darkens).

Comment: Did you check you can collapse your expanded item after scroll? Maybe the item is seen as expanded but is managed as collapsed for android

Comment: How can the item be seen as expanded but managed as collapsed? I return the View in getView depending on whether the item is expanded or not, so if Android considers it collapsed, then wouldn't getView return a collapsed view? I added some more relevant code if that helps.

Comment: I just ask because sometimes android do not manage our views as expected.

Comment: How would I check if Android is managing my views as expected? That could be the problem, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "managing view". Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you have twice "holder.valueEditText.setTag("")", you can just tag once

Comment: That wasn't code written by me. I commented out one of the tags just now to test, and unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: could you add the whole layout for item (collapsed and expanded), and maybe the whole adapter. You should use debug mode and see if the item is recreated after scroll, or what element takes the focus...

Comment: Added. The item is recreated after scroll (checked with a print statement). How would I check which element takes focus?

Comment: That code is pretty unreadable. Start moving stuff to private methods and maybe the issue will be more clear.

Comment: a last attempt: in getView, for a button, try button.setOnclickListener, and call cancelClicked in the onClick method for example. And as suggest m0skit0, refactoring is good. clickable=true is unnessecary for a button, like orientation for relativelayout

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've tried doing setOnClickListener directly in getView, but it seems to have no effect. I'll continue to dig around to see if I can find the issue. Thanks again!